# open other application via vb .net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

What is this code correct to open other application via vb .net?

```
Module OpenZone
Sub Main()
    OpenZoneServer("C:\Users\Andre Pabertiyan\Desktop\")
End Sub

Private Sub OpenZoneServer(ByVal f As String)
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    startInfo.FileName = "DZoneModule.exe"
    startInfo.Arguments = f
    Process.Start(startInfo)
End Sub
End Module
```

If this code is correct how i get this code to call into the main program?

Answer (score 0):

Is `f` is the path to the application or really an argument?

arguments are for example `/f` `/d` or whatever your application supports as arguments. some applications may support a path to a file or directory as an argument too. your path however contains a space which will most likely split the argument into two and would not be supported, to fix this you surround the path with parentheses (you have to escape them):

```
Sub Main()
    OpenZoneServer("""C:\Users\Andre Pabertiyan\Desktop\""")
End Sub
```

if you meant the path to the application:

```
startInfo.FileName = f & "DZoneModule.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Shell() function to call specific executable.
For example :

```
shell("C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe")
```

Comment: i use shell() but when i wanna open other program in desktop is useless... i use like this shell("C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\DZoneModule.exe")

Comment: Well, its working fine. e.g. I have a .exe file.

I tried this : 

    Shell("C:\Users\Mahadev\Desktop\Windows7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool-Installer-en-US.exe")

and its working perfectly fine.

Comment: Or if you want to use shortcut in Shell(), go to Properties of that shortcut file, copy Target Text and paste into shell(<paste here>) and program will run the external executable.